# How can I find all *.js file in directory recursively in Linux?

Tags: linux, find

In Linux, how can I find all `*.js` files in a directory recursively?  The output should be an absolute path (like `/pub/home/user1/folder/jses/file.js`)

**this answer worked for me:**

```
find $PWD -name '*.js' > out.txt
```

It finds all *.js files, output absolute path, writes the results into out.txt.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

`find /abs/path/ -name '*.js'`

**Edit:**  As Brian points out, add `-type f` if you want only plain files, and not directories, links, etc.

Comment: Since he asked for files, you should also add `-type f` just on the off chance there is a directory ending in ".js".

Answer (score 16):

Use `find` on the command line:

```
find /my/directory -name '*.js'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the list, then you should ask here: http://unix.stackexchange.com

The answer is: `cd / && find -name *.js`

If you want to implement this, you have to specify the language.